# Unique solution to an integral equation with expectations

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, integral-equations

Let $X$ be a random variable distributed according to the distribution function $P$ and density function $p$ with full support on compact interval $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}_+$.

I am trying to find a solution to the following integral equation:

$$ \int_a^b \left( g(x) - k y \right) f(x,y) p(x) dx = \int_a^b \left( g(x) - k d \right) f(x,d) p(x) dx + \int_y^d \int_a^b f(x,s) p(x) dx ds, \: (1) $$
for $y \in [c,d]\subset \mathbb{R}_+$,
where $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is a given function that is continuously differentiable and increasing in $x$, and $ k \neq 0$ is a constant.

A point-wise solution exists – that is, a solution to
$$(g(x)-ky)f(x,y)=\left( g(x) - k d \right) f(x,d) + \int_y^df(x,s)ds$$
is $$f(x,y)=h(x) \left( g(x) - k y \right)^{\frac{1-k}{k}} \qquad \qquad (2) $$ for any $h(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ (note that the trivial solution $f(x,y)=0$ for all $(x,y)\in[a,b]\times[c,d]$ is given by $h(x)=0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$). This solution also solves the integral equation (1) with expected values.

Are there any other solutions for (1)? When is (2) the unique solution?

Comment: It seems that this integral equation comes from some larger problem. Please let us know where this is coming from. It's very hard to work in purely abstract notions.

Comment: Thank you Radost for your comment. I'm sorry but knowing the context does not give any help for solving the problem: I've specified the questions as much as I could.